# The most simple task is giving me nullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
   Collection Class


private E[] data;


@Override
       public boolean add(E element) {
       //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HAPPENS ON NEXT LINE
                data[actualSize] = element;
                actualSize++;

          return true;
       }
```

Main

```
        System.out.println ("Enter the integer to be added:   ");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        ac.add(n);
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception after the comment line in the collection class.... WHY?!?!?

EDIT: So my issue is I need E[] data to be resized, how do I resize data? My teacher never told us about this "E" buisness, she never even told us what the hell this thing "E" is called or used for.

Comment: It generally helps if you at least add the language you're using to the tags, so you get the attention of people who might be able to get you an answer. You've also shown no information about what `data` is, or how it's created/allocated, which would be helpful. (Also, you *are* aware that you've hard-coded `add` to always use element `0` of `data`, which means you can have only one item in the collection?)

Comment: `data` must be null -- your problem lies elsewhere. (Hint: why aren't you resizing `data`?)

Comment: I used 0 instead of actualSize in an attempt to isolate the null value, but it didn't help at all. and data is initialized as: private E[] data;

Comment: sigh... how do I resize data? My teacher never told us about this "E" buisness, she never even told us what the hell this thing "E" is called or used for.

Comment: No; `data` is _declared_ to refer to an array having a certain type and scope, but the (default) value is `null`. Please edit your question to state the problem and include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your current appraoch.

Answer (score 6):

> WHY?!?!?

Because `data` has not been initialized.  The `null` is the default value for an instance variable that has not been initialized.

---

But there seems to be a some more fundamental problem:

- You seem to be under the impression that Java arrays will magically allocate themselves with the right size ... and that they will grow.  In fact, when you allocate an array, your program must explicitly say how many elements it has.  And once it has been allocated, the array's size is fixed.
- The code seems to be a trying to implement a generic type of some kind (where `E`) is the generic type parameter.

---

> So my issue is I need E[] data to be resized, how do I resize data?

You create a new array with the right size, copy the elements from the old to the new, and update the `data` variable to point to the new array.  Check your notes / text book on how to create a new array in Java.

> My teacher never told us about this "E" buisness, she never even told us what the hell this thing "E" is called or used for.

1. It is most likely a generic type parameter.
2. I'm pretty sure she *would have* told the class about it, or set the relevant part of your Java text book for the class to read.

(Assuming that `E` is a generic type parameter, allocating a new `E[]` array instance without an "unchecked conversion" warning is a little tricky.  Maybe your instructor *has* gotten ahead of what the class is currently capable of ...)

Comment: How can I not make it null? My entire lab deal with these e as elements but of course none of that is in my notes nor in the chapter, I just don't have a clue what to do, I just want to add an element e to data, how could I resize data?